# Finding the nearest neighbor of a vector in a set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, polytopes, quadratic-programming

Given a set $P = \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \mathrm{A}\textbf{x} \leq \textbf{b} \}$ and a vector $\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where all of $\textbf{x}$'s and $\textbf{y}$'s coordinates are non-negative, and $\mathrm{A}$ is a matrix, $\textbf{b}$ is a vector forming a linear inequality.

How can I find $\textbf{y}$'s nearest neighbor in $P$, that is a $\textbf{z} \in P$ vector with minimal Euclidean distance from $\textbf{y}$?

Comment: Please provide context for the question. Where did you come up with it? What have you tried? etc. Also, be sure to define all the notation you use. Otherwise your question will attract downvotes

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is equivalent to

$$\min \|x-y\|^2$$

s.t.  $$Ax \le b, x \ge 0.$$

This is a [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem. Do check out the solvers on the site.